# 2d Interpolation and 1d array to 2d array

Tags: arrays, interpolation

I have a data look like as below,

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 30 | 3 |
| 22 | 32 | 2.5 |
| 24 | 34 | 1.6 |
| 26 | 36 | 0.8 |

I want to do 2d interpolation for this data and I want to get z values based on x_new and y_new values which I newly define. For example I want to know z values for (x_new=23.5, y_new=32.50)

I tried this code for 2d interpolation on my data:

```
x_g, y_g = x, y
data = z

x, y = np.meshgrid(x_g, y_g)
    
interp = LinearNDInterpolator((x, y), data)
```

But I received this error.

```
invalid shape for input data points
```

I think, firstly I should arrange my data which will be able to do meshgrid. I can arrange my data 2d dataframe. But I couldn't figure it out.

Can you please help me to through this problem?